# The clause in "it is adjective that clause " structure

Tags: clauses, subjects, objects

{it} + {passive verb} + [that] + {clause}

It + is said + that + Jesse Owens was one of the most important athletes of the 20th Century.

"Jesse Owens was one of the most important athletes of the 20th Century" is a objective clause or subjective clause ?
I think it is a subject clause ,my fried think it is a object clause.
In my analyse:
It  is the dummy pronoun.
`Jesse Owens was one of the most important athletes of the 20th Century`  is extraposed subject.

Comment: Would you define what are subjective and objective clauses? What is the basis of your 'thinking'?

Comment: Define objective and subjective. E.g. how would you classify "I hate Bill Clinton"? Subjective because it's a personal opinion, or objective because I do hate him, as a matter of undeniable fact?